# Firefox keeps crashing on Ubuntu 14.04 even in safe mode

Tags: 14.04, firefox, crash

It's been happening for the last two days. There is no particular reason why it happens. The last time it happened was when I was trying to purchase something on Amazon. It just wouldn't let me open that page to complete my purchase.

```
Add-ons: online-accounts%40lists.launchpad.net:0.5,%7B2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66%7D:2014.08.06.beta,ubufox%40ubuntu.com:3.0,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:39.0,%7Bd10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d%7D:2.6.9.1-signed,langpack-en-GB%40firefox.mozilla.org:39.0,langpack-en-ZA%40firefox.mozilla.org:39.0,webapps-team%40lists.launchpad.net:3.0.2
AsyncPluginInit: 0
BuildID: 20150629114848
CrashTime: 1436864191
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 7ffffffff0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1436586661
Notes: OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile  -- 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3 -- texture_from_pixmap

ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 16513
StartupTime: 1436864132
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
URL: about:newtab
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 39.0
useragent_locale: chrome://global/locale/intl.properties

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

I tried running it in safe mode, and it crashed again when I tried opening the page. Here is the message I got from the terminal when that crash happened:

```
firefox -safe-mode

(process:2867): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:2867): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:2867): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:2867): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:2867): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
NOT SANDBOXED
[fresh] [warning] ppb_var_var_to_utf8, 'var' is not a string, (0)
[fresh  2947] not implemented: PPB_OpenGLES2DrawBuffers(Dev);1.0
[fresh  2947] [PPB] {zilch} ppb_network_monitor_update_network_list
[fresh  2947] [PPB] {zilch} ppb_flash_set_instance_always_on_top instance=11, on_top=1

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel::Call] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel::Call] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

I cannot understand what exactly ails Firefox, because the same thing might happen even when I try to open a simple HTML page (my Gmail account, for example). Looking for solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions. I think the problem was with my Flash plugin, and once I turned it off, I have not had Firefox crashing since. This does solve my problem, of course, but only temporarily. I would like to know if there is any fix to this, so that I don't have to turn off my plugin, in order to keep Firefox from crashing.

Comment: Pretty much works without hurting me too much, so I am going to go with this as my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
mv ~/{.mozilla,mozilla.bak} 
# this command remames ~/.mozzilla (firefox) config folder to mozilla.bak
```

Or someone had the same error and fixed it by disable hardware acceleration: `https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193339`